# In SQL optimization, should we always use LIMIT to prevent the system to download a lot of data? Or any other better solution?

Tags: java, sql, optimization

Ok, say, there a table that have million record. Then we somehow need a query

```
Select column1 from tbl where column1 like '%a%';
```

Suppose that the result of this query will be used in a program for checking some info, & this program need all result data for checking --> so we can not take the data by piecemeal.

If we take data by piecemeal, then we have to use LIMIT.

But if we run that query, then it gonna download lot of data & make the system slow down.

Question: is there any other elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do with the data, you can ask the database to do (a part of) it. Databases can usually perform a lot of operations, like adding, subtracting, taking the maximum or minimum, averaging, and so on.

Without knowing the exact type of processing, its hard to tell what your exact alternatives are, though.

Comment: this seem to be a good alternative, just like u build entirely checking program by using store procedure in DB, but it's hard to learn stored procedure language.

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, or pointed you in a good direction, please mark it as accepted. It will encourage people to answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

> his program need all result data for checking

If a program needs *all* that data for checking whatever it needs to check, then there is no way around it: you need to download all the data from the RDBMS.

However, oftentimes you do not need to store all that data in memory: if checking the data can be done by examining one row at a time, you could read the data one row at a time, check it, and then discard the row. This approach presents a good alternative to paging, because you need to send only one query, non-paged queries are typically simpler to use than their paged counterparts.

Comment: Did u mean I have to call multiple queries, & call 1 query at a time?

Comment: @Tom When you use a paged approach, you need to run the same paged query several times. The exact number of times depends on the number of pages: if you have `N` pages, you query `N+1` times (the "plus one" comes from the need to check if there's no data left after your last paged query). When you use a non-paged approach, you run only one query.

Comment: @Tom You are welcome! If this answers your question, consider accepting the answer by clicking the grey check mark next to it. This would let others know that you are no longer actively looking for a better answer, and earn you a new badge on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

When your Query is as simple as the one you have shown above there is not really many things you can do to make it quicker. if you have loads of data you will have to expect it to take slightly longer. just use `LIMIT` and check how long it takes to query 10000 records then slowly increase this and test performance

Oh sorry just realized you said you need all the data.. Perhaps try breaking the query out a bit, eg searching only the minimal possible and then when you need to use or display the data run a query that uses a result from the inital one as a search parameter?

i can only assume the one you show here is an example, or is it the actual query your running?

Comment: the above query is just an easy example for u to see, not the real one.

Comment: so for example is there anyway you can just pull all of the ID fields (lets just say ID but you see what i mean some form of unique identifier) this would be quick, and then when you need to use the data just do a search on that one identifier if that makes sense that way your initial query is fast and subseqent qeuries will be too because they are working on pulling one set of data only

Comment: thax u, i understood what u mean